# Theming own field: how do I control the outer markup?

Tags: theming

I'm working on a custom field and formatter and right now I'm at the theming stage. My formatter should render a list of items as a run-in list of badges, much like the tags here on Drupal answers. Currently I am getting a top-to-bottom list, as the fields get the Drupal's default wrappers:

```
<div class="field-items">
  <div class="field-item even">...</div>
  <div class="field-item odd">...</div>
</div>
```

I thought it would be more appropriate if I had a control over the wrappers markup and delivered something like:

```
<div class="my-field-wrapper">
  <span>Value 1</span><span>Value 2</span><span>etc.</span>
</div>
```

I have already managed to control the `span` markup via a custom tpl, but I'm unsure how I am supposed to theme the field's outer markup to suppress the default wrappers.
Of course I know I could override `div` styling by setting `display: inline-block`, but I treat this as my first theming excercise hoping to learn.

Comment: Did you copy 'field.tpl.php'? You should of been able to edit the wrapper there.

Comment: Nope, I didn't, I'm right now looking into `comment.module` > `template_preprocess_comment_wrapper` to see how they did it, but I am not sure I could go the same way.

Comment: did you read this already?
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7

Comment: @Geeo, so I created `field--my-field.tpl.php` (my-field being the machine name of the field provided by my module), put the desired markup there, put the file into my module's directory, cleared cache twice, and nothing shows up. Should this suggestion technique work in this case?

Comment: @Artur: can you paste here the exact machine name you used for your field and the exact filename of your tpl file?

Comment: The filename = `field--chemical-hazards.tpl.php`, the machine name of the field: `chemical_hazards` (as defined by hook_field_info). So, please keep in mind - this is not the machine name of the field as entered on the content type edit form, but rather the field id provided by my module. This, I suspect, might be causing misunderstanding in this thread :) and misfunctioning as well.

Comment: Can you please try this as the tpl filename: field--chemical_hazards.tpl.php ?

Comment: Tried that again, cleared cache, no go. :( I'm alread successfully using `chemical_hazards_phrase.tpl.php` which is for each individual item. *The bot is starting to be chasing us away to chat for intensive discussion...*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4175/discussion-between-geeo-and-artur)

Answer (score 2):

The way to correctly theme what you are asking is shown here: [theme_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7)

In particular:

> This is the default theme implementation to display the value of a
>   field. Theme developers who are comfortable with overriding theme
>   functions may do so in order to customize this markup. This function
>   can be overridden with varying levels of specificity. For example, for
>   a field named 'body' displayed on the 'article' content type, any of
>   the following functions will override this default implementation. The
>   first of these functions that exists is used:
>
> ```
> THEMENAME_field__body__article()
> THEMENAME_field__article()
> THEMENAME_field__body()
> THEMENAME_field()
> ```
>
> Theme developers who prefer to customize templates instead of
>   overriding functions may copy the "field.tpl.php" from the
>   "modules/field/theme" folder of the Drupal installation to somewhere
>   within the theme's folder and customize it, just like customizing
>   other Drupal templates such as page.tpl.php or node.tpl.php. However,
>   it takes longer for the server to process templates than to call a
>   function, so for websites with many fields displayed on a page, this
>   can result in a noticeable slowdown of the website. For these
>   websites, developers are discouraged from placing a field.tpl.php file
>   into the theme's folder, but may customize templates for specific
>   fields. For example, for a field named 'body' displayed on the
>   'article' content type, any of the following templates will override
>   this default implementation. The first of these templates that exists
>   is used:
>
> ```
> field--body--article.tpl.php
> field--article.tpl.php
> field--body.tpl.php
> field.tpl.php
> ```
>
> So, if the body field on the article content type needs customization,
>   a field--body--article.tpl.php file can be added within the theme's
>   folder. Because it's a template, it will result in slightly more time
>   needed to display that field, but it will not impact other fields, and
>   therefore, is unlikely to cause a noticeable change in website
>   performance. A very rough guideline is that if a page is being
>   displayed with more than 100 fields and they are all themed with a
>   template instead of a function, it can add up to 5% to the time it
>   takes to display that page. This is a guideline only and the exact
>   performance impact depends on the server configuration and the details
>   of the website.

Finding the right naming convention is somewhat a mess, so I suggest you to try the [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module in order to find out all the possible names for your template file.

Here is the [naming convention guide](http://drupal.org/node/1089656). Given your comment my best guess would then be: field--field-chemical-hazards.tpl.php

Answer (score 1):

Copy the 'field.tpl.php' file located at modules > field > theme

Paste this file to your theme 'templates' folder

This will override the default field template but if you want to be more specific, look at the commments within the file for examples

```
field-name-[field_name].tpl.php
field-type-[field_type].tpl.php
```

Edit the markup in the code, taking consideration of the conditional statements

You will need to clear the caches when adding a template file

Comment: I might not have been clear about my goal. What I want to do is to deliver a tpl file as a part of *my module*, say - "an installable feature". I'm familiar with the suggestion technique, but this is kind of one level higher. At this moment I want to prepare a default template file that would be subject to end-user overrides. Therefore I should not touch the theme directory, but my module's directory instead. Hence my question - whether the technique you suggest will work for my module.